# Is there a way I can force Telerik RadGrid to always show 5 rows regardless of my datasource has that much rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik, telerik-grid

I want to force Telerik RadGrid to show every 5 row, regardless of how many (lower than 5) rows I have in my data source I'm binding it to. For example, If I have 3 records in my datasource, I want it to show all those three records plus 2 empty rows. I was thinking about adding two empty rows to my datatable I'm binding to, but I wanted to know is there a better way.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, it might also be a good idea to post the question to Telerik's forum for the [Grid](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx).

Comment: Yes you're right. I'm hoping yo get my answer here.

Comment: I failed on spelling binding, good catch there. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea of adding rows to the datatable that the Radgrid is bound to is by far the easiest:

This is just an example, using the AdventureWorks 2012 db.

---

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    String ConnString = @"Data Source=J-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2012;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select top 3 AddressID,AddressLine1,City,StateProvinceID,PostalCode from Person.Address ", conn);

    DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();

    conn.Open();
    try
    {
        adapter.Fill(myDataTable);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    if(myDataTable.Rows.Count < 5)
    {
        DataRow dr = null;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5-myDataTable.Rows.Count ; i++)
        {
            myDataTable.Rows.Add(new object[]{});
        }
    }

    RadGrid1.DataSource = myDataTable;
}
```

---

[image]